# How Can I make sure there is no missing Value in mysql query string php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php class and method that creates records into Mysql Table as follows;

```
<?php
class Site{

// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "sites";

// object properties
public $id;
public $name;
public $location;
public $saddress;
public $duration;
public $created;

// create new site record
function create(){

// to get time stamp for 'created' field
$this->created=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// insert query
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
        SET
    site_name       = :name,
    site_location   = :location,
    site_address     = :address,
    site_duration   = :duration,
    created         = :created";
    

// prepare the query
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

// sanitize
$this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
$this->location=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->location));
$this->saddress=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->saddress));
$this->duration=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->duration));
$this->created=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->created));




// bind the values
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $this->location);
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $this->saddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':duration', $this->duration);
$stmt->bindParam(':created', $this->created);



// execute the query, also check if query was successful
if($stmt->execute()){
    
    return true;
}else{
    $this->showError($stmt);
    return false;
}

}
public function showError($stmt){
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
echo "</pre>";
}

}
?>
```

My problem is that anything I try to submit my HTML form I will have an error which says:

```
Array
(
[0] => 23000
[1] => 1048
[2] => Column 'site_address' cannot be null
)
```

I am confused because my HTLM form fields and database table column Fields names are correctly written and whenever I remove the site_address field from my query, the other data get inserted into the table so someone should please help.
Here is the implementation of class;

```
    <?php
// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db       = $database->getConnection();
  
// pass connection to objects
$Construction = new Site($db);

// if the form was submitted - 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 // set user property values

$Construction->name         = $_POST['sitename'];
$Construction->location     = $_POST['sitelocation'];
$Construction->saddress     = $_POST["siteaddress"];
$Construction->duration     = $_POST['siteduration'];
       

//Check if Construction Site already Exist
if($Construction->siteExists())
{

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                          <strong>Sorry!</strong> User Already Exist.
                    </div>';  




}else{


$Construction->create();


}
}
?>
```

Comment: does your database have data in it ?

Comment: `$saddress` should be `$this->saddress`

Comment: you shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` and `strip_tags` when storing in the database. They should be used when displaying the data on a web page, to prevent XSS.

Comment: @user837288 yes my database has data in it. Only the column site_address that is not inserting into the table

Comment: I never see `$this->name` or any of those properties get assigned. You never show us how you are using `new Site`.

Comment: @StackSlave guess you can see from my edited coded now

Comment: I never see `session_start();` or any `$_SESSION` assignment. Looks like it's binding as an empty String which would be `= NULL` in MySQL.

Comment: @StackSlave I have no problem with session management. The problem is the query and may be the database table

Comment: I have checked whether the HTML form field 'siteaddress' is not empty or not but I discovered that nothing was wrong from the input field. Now I understand that the problem is either from my query string or database table so can someone help from here

Answer (score 0):

you're posting

> $_POST["siteaddress"];

when its supposed to be

> Column 'site_address' cannot be null

try `$_POST['site_address']` instead

> site_address     = :address,

shouldnt this be saddress???

Comment: I have corrected that but nothing is working till now